# Convergence or divergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2+\cos k}{\sqrt{k+1}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to determine whether or not

> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2+\cos k}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$

converges or not.

I have tried using the ratio test but this isn't getting me very far. Is this a sensible way to go about it or should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may observe that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^M \frac{2+\cos k}{\sqrt{k+1}} \geq \sum_{k=1}^M \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}
$$ leading to the divergence of the initial series.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac {2+\cos k}{\sqrt {k+1}}\geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac {1}{\sqrt {k+1}}=\infty. $$

Comment: How did you get the inequality?

Comment: It's because $\cos k$ is never less than $-1$, so adding $2$ gives you something that's never less than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

I initially missed the inequality the two other answers provide.

Another (more complicated but sometimes useful) way is to note that $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\cos k}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ converges via Dirichlet test. The original series is therefore $\text{ divergent }+ \text{ convergent }= \text{ divergent } $